# unable to install toast notification due to incompatibility

Tags: c#, wpf, notifications

I got the following error when installing the toast notification package

> PM> Install-Package Mantin.Controls.Wpf.Notification
>   Installing 'Mantin.Controls.Wpf.Notification 3.2.0.0'.
>   You are downloading Mantin.Controls.Wpf.Notification from Lawrence Mantin, the license agreement to which is available at https://toastspopuphelpballoon.codeplex.com/license. Check the package for additional dependencies, which may come with their own license agreement(s). Your use of the package and dependencies constitutes your acceptance of their license agreements. If you do not accept the license agreement(s), then delete the relevant components from your device.
>
> Successfully installed 'Mantin.Controls.Wpf.Notification 3.2.0.0'.
>   Adding 'Mantin.Controls.Wpf.Notification 3.2.0.0' to App. Uninstalling
>   'Mantin.Controls.Wpf.Notification 3.2.0.0'. Successfully uninstalled
>   'Mantin.Controls.Wpf.Notification 3.2.0.0'. Install failed. Rolling
>   back...
>
> Install-Package : Could not install package 'Mantin.Controls.Wpf.Notification 3.2.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is change your target framework to 4.6 or higher.

Comment: Go to your project's properties >> Application >> Target Framework.  Change to 4.6 or greater.